# Table cells not showing up

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am beginning iOS programming and I have hit a roadblock. I have a login view controller that redirects the control(after checking user authentication,etc) to a tab controller(homescreen) using the following code:

```
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    UITabBarController *viewController = (UITabBarController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"homescreen"];
    [self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

The first view controller in home screen is a navigation controller leading to Subscription View Controller (a Table View Controller). From app delegate.m, I am trying to send an array of values (chefs) which the table can use to populate itself using the following code:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"homescreen"];
UINavigationController *navigationController = [tabBarController viewControllers][0];
SubscriptionViewController *controller = [navigationController viewControllers][0];
controller.chefs = _chefs;
```

However, the table shows up empty. The NSMutable array "chefs" has been populated appropriately and in the storyboard, the table cell values (UILabels,etc.) have been hooked up correctly to their counterpart values inside Content View. As a check, I NSLogged the [self.chefs count] value inside Subscription view controller:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
// Return the number of rows in the section.
NSLog(@"%d",[self.chefs count]);
return [self.chefs count];

}
```

However, this returned 0. I suspect, I am not broadcasting the array properly.

EDIT:
I removed the login view controller and made the Tab bar controller the root view controller. And then used this piece of code:

```
UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
UINavigationController *navigationController = [tabBarController viewControllers][0];
SubscriptionViewController *controller = [navigationController viewControllers][0];
controller.chefs = _chefs;
```

Now I can see the correct cells. I am not sure if the way I am redirecting the control from login view to tab bar controller is correct OR using the way I am using storyboard ID to broadcast the array is correct. Any pointers?

Comment: Try: `NSLog(@"self.Chefs: %@", self.chefs);` to make sure the array exists.

Comment: @Logan, tried it, returns null

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your array isn't being initialized properly, when you assign it like this:

```
controller.chefs = _chefs;
```

Before doing anything with `_chefs` make sure it's initialized somewhere:

```
_chefs = [[NSArray alloc]init];
```

Comment: I am using _chefs = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:20] in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions (Appdelegate.m), where I am also setting controller.chefs=_chefs.

Comment: Hmmm, do you call that and initialize it before you set it as the `controller.chefs` property?

Comment: _chefs = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:20];
    
    Chef *chef = [[Chef alloc]init];
    chef.name = @"John Doe";
    [_chefs addObject:chef];
    
    chef.name = @"Doe John";
    [_chefs addObject:chef]; I use this to initialize the array before assigning it to controller.chefs

Comment: Hmm, are you reinitializing the controller.chefs somewhere like viewDidLoad?

Comment: I am only initializing controller.chefs once(in the app delegate.m method)

Comment: I'm not really sure what's happening here, sorry I'm unable to help.  There's something going on with your dictionary, but at this point, I'm out of troubleshooting ideas perhaps add more code to your question.

Comment: Thanks Logan, I will try figuring out what's going wrong, will add more code.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe _chefs is being released? Try assigning like this

```
controller.chefs = [NSArray arrayWithArray:_chefs];
```

Also make sure the table in controller is reloaded after your assignment. Maybe implement the setter in controller like this:

```
-(void)setChefs:(NSArray*)chefs
{
    _chefs = chefs;
    [self.tableview reloadData];
}
```

Comment: Tried with the different assignment method and also used a setter, but the rows are still not showing up and the array passed is empty.

Comment: If you put a breakpoint at controller.chefs = _chefs; does _chefs have anything in it?

Comment: Yes it does, it shows 2 objects, makes sense as I have added two objects to _chefs.

Comment: Do you have initialization code for chefs somewhere in SubscriptionViewController? Maybe in viewDidLoad()? You may be overriding the value of chefs.

Comment: What is the value of controller.chefs right after that line?

Comment: The viewDidLoad() only initializes the background of the view at this point. In the SubscriptionViewController.h, I have the array property set as : @property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *chefs; Is this ok?

Comment: Yeah, nothing obviously wrong with your property assignment. When do you call reloadData() on your tableView?

Comment: I have not implemented the reloadData() yet. However, I have got the cells to show up by changing the root controller (ref:edit). Any ideas on what I am doing wrong? And thanks for helping me on this :)

Comment: You don't need to implement reloadData, you just need to call it. That's the method that will reload your tableview once you've assigned a data source. reloadData will get called automatically when the table is loaded, but that may be before you actually assign the data source (in this case chefs), so the table comes up empty. so somewhere like viewDidLoad would be a good place to call [tableview reloadData]; but you have to make sure chefs is assigned by then.